# Chisquare test and K-S test for a given set of Random Numbers in range [0,num_max] in R?

Tags: r, testing, random, chi-squared

I have made a random number generator and generated N numbers in range 0 to 10007, I want to test how good is this generator in R.

Comment: What is the distribution? Are they distributed as N(0,1), or U(0,1), or something else??

Comment: U(0,1), also please tell me, How to interpret about pvalue?

Comment: I guess your problem is not R, but maths, because your question is not about programing. Maybe you would have more luck on http://stats.stackexchange.com/ (also, here is the problem with evaluating random number generators: http://bit.ly/1gzVa1C )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ks.test` to test if your sample matches the specified distribution. For instance, we can compare the output of `runif` to the U(0, 1) distribution:

```
set.seed(144)
x <- runif(1000, 0, 1)
ks.test(x, "punif", 0, 1)
#   One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
# 
# data:  x
# D = 0.0326, p-value = 0.2374
# alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

The `D` value states that the empirical cdf of your samples differs from the cdf of the U(0, 1) distribution by a maximum of 0.0326. The p-value says that there's a 0.2374 probability that the empirical cdf of 1000 random samples from a random variable R will differ from the cdf of R by `D` or more.

Comment: I don't think your last sentence is correct.

Comment: so, does that mean a high p value is good?

I applied Chisquare test and result is: 
X-squared = 1662, df = 10006, p-value = 1

Is it good or bad?

ks test gave p-value = 0.8775

Comment: @user3392464 A high p-value means the tests did not prove your data differed from the distribution you're comparing against. If you're creating a prng, that would be good.